# How to subtract time in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

How can I substract `checkout_time` from `purchase_time` to find total time spent on the website? Please view the DataFrame here: [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nrh1p.png)

I used the following code but it gives me an error. The format for time is 1/26/2017 14:44:

```
df['time_to_purchase'] = df.purchase_time - df.checkout_time
```

However I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to convert the dtype of the columns to something that Pandas can recognize for doing datetime arithmetic:

```
fmt = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'  # or: infer_datetime_format=True

df['purchase_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['purchase_time'],
                                     format=fmt,
                                     errors='coerce')
df['checkout_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['checkout_time'],
                                     format=fmt,
                                     errors='coerce')
```

Using `errors='coerce'` in [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) will force unrecognized/unparseable dates to become `NaT` ("not a time").

Comment: Thank you that works! I also found another piece of code which is a little longer.   
df['checkout_time'] = pd.DataFrame({'checkout_time' : pd.to_datetime(all_data['checkout_time'], infer_datetime_format=True)})

Comment: I would not recommend that longer line.  No need to create an entirely new DataFrame in the call

Comment: Thank you that makes sense.